# check mark disappear after moving to new ip address

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I moved my web server to another ip address. But "Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation" still refer the images from the old ip address. All the checkmark in my dashboard are disappeared, no matter for radio or checkbox.

Here is an example:

[image]

**Update:**
I checked the console and found an error message: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". 
Here is a screenshot for error from console:
[image]
What do I need to do??? How can I update the css and js file? Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you for all helping.

Comment: Every checkboxes and radios on every pages?

Comment: yes. All pages and checkboxes in dashboard.

Comment: What's happened if you click the box? Will it show checked? Or it still in empty?

Comment: it still empty. but when I check the source code, the box is marked as checked

Comment: update your js to some new version, it seems like js issue

Comment: I am sorry. But how to update js???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help.
I found out the reason for a long time searching. Cause I moved an existing complicated website to a new ip address. The [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module does affect images, css and js.

Here are some solutions that I found might be useful:

- **Check $base_url in setting.php file** (might be set as old url/ domain name/ ip address)
- **Uncommend "#RewriteBase /" in .htaccess file then flushing the cache** (Do not try this unless you know what you are doing)
- **Unable Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation Module** (It will compass your js/css, this might cause some problem. Just unable it, use your
  original css file) -- This works for me.

Here are some references I used here:

1. [Need help changing domain/url on existing drupal site...](https://www.drupal.org/node/1688552)
2. [images not showing / displaying after moving to localhost (Wamp
   Server)](https://www.drupal.org/node/445522)

Comment: Glad to know that you can find the clue....

Comment: You can also force AdvAgg to generate new aggregates from `admin/config/development/performance/advagg/operations` and opening the **Drastic Measures** fieldset and opening **Force New Aggregates** and click button **Increment Global Counter**. We had success generating new aggregates (this re-generates with new domain too).

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for all your commands. @Beebee's method works like charming. Everything works fine right now.